# Adjective to describe period before creation

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Especially in the context of history or Bible studies, we see the term "antediluvean" to describe the period of time before the "great flood." I'm basically searching for a scholarly, specific term to describe the period of time that happens before the creation of life and/or the earth. Some nouns come to mind here, such as 'chaos', but I'm interested in an adjective form.

For illustration:

> In the _______ period, deities tend to be more passive as opposed to
> active.

Comment: "Pre-Creation Period"

Comment: "Saint Augustine had two answers to those who asked what was God doing before creation. Jokingly he said, God was preparing Hell for people who ask such questions. On a serious level, he noted there was no time before God created and hence the question is meaningless." [You're delving into big theological issues](https://www.blueletterbible.org/faq/don_stewart/don_stewart_643.cfm) so you can read [a lot](https://iep.utm.edu/god-time/#SH4c) [about](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/cosmology-theology/) the topic, but there doesn't seem to be a particular term for it.

Comment: From a human perspective, anything that occurred before the creation of the universe is "past". In eternity (i.e., the realm of timelessness), however, there is no past, since eternity and time are two different entities. I find myself using the term "eternity past" to indicate pre-chronology (though there is not such a word). As for post-chronology, I use the term "eternity future." Time and eternity are different realms of existence. Time is a creation of God, and there would not have been a need for eternity future had our first parents had not sinned. They were created to be immortal.

Comment: @rhetorician It's tempting to see time in the space/time/matter context of our created universe. A linear progression, with creation occupying a shortish though important interval along the timeline. But though there is not frozenness in eternity, the change-line is not directly comparable to time.

Comment: @StuartF There could be potential for those kind of pitfalls but, for clarity, the context of this sentence is for the ancient animistic/polytheistic of the Near East. So I'm looking for a way to partition the time periods that the religions evolved in. Antediluvean has a nice ring to it, but I struggle to match its eloquence/sophistication for "before creation."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go with *premundane*,

> **premundane**, adj.: existing before the creation of the world ([Merriam Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/premundane)

The definition is almost exactly what you're looking for, and even if your reader hasn't previously encountered the word, it's fairly self-explanatory (pre>before, mundus>world).

There's also the British version, *antemundane*,

> **antemundane**, adj.: pertaining to that which existed or occurred before the creation of the world ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/antemundane))

Comment: "It's fairly self-explanatory", except that 'mundane' is commonly used to denote something banal. Nevertheless, great answer.

Comment: I knew it! I knew there was some word for this concept similar to antediluvian! Thank you very much

Comment: @ArashHowaida, no problem!

Answer (score 2):

There is also ***pretemporal***, also spelt ***pre-temporal***, which can be used with the meaning:

> Occurring or happening *before the existence of time* (Wiktionary)

Not to be confused with its homonym *[pretemporal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretemporal)* (situated in front of the temporal bone).

Karl Barth speaks in his *[Ethics](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dtEUAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA121&dq=%22pre-temporal%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUm-achPv7AhVOT8AKHQdTBJwQ6AF6BAgEEAI)* about

> manifestations of the ***pre - temporal*** , co - temporal , and post - temporal eternity of God.